# Awk script, counting the number of +value and -value

Tags: linux, awk

in fowlloing list are the prices Benzin everyday, i want for each day the difference to the previous day (the first day does not appear in the output)

- at the end of the statement: the number of days on which the price has rised,
  stayed the same or not avalible.

> ```
> list of benzin prise
> ```

```
01.05.2021 156
02.05.2021 154
03.05.2021 151
04.05.2021 152
05.05.2021 148
06.05.2021 149
07.05.2021 147
08.05.2021 150
09.05.2021 150
10.05.2021 152
11.05.2021 157
12.05.2021 151
13.05.2021 147
14.05.2021 144
15.05.2021 150
```

the output should looks like this :

```
•   02.05.2021: -2
•   03.05.2021: -3
•   04.05.2021: 1
•   05.05.2021: -4
•   06.05.2021: 1
•   07.05.2021: -2
•   08.05.2021: 3
•   09.05.2021: 0
•   10.05.2021: 2
•   11.05.2021: 5
•   12.05.2021: -6
•   13.05.2021: -4
•   14.05.2021: -3
•   15.05.2021: 6
•   
•   Number increased: 6
•   Number missing or equal: 8
```

I tried this code but still ist some how not complate, im working on it:

awk 'NR>2 {print $1 " " $2-p} {p=$2}' <benzinprise

i stil need to count the nummbers which increased and not increased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following.

```
awk '
FNR>1{
  diff=($2-prevVal)
  if(diff>0){ increase++ }
  else      { missing++  }
  print $1": "diff
}
{
  prevVal=$2
}
END{
  print "Number increased: "increase+0 ORS "Number missing or equal: " missing+0
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR>1{                        ##If line is not first line then do following.
  diff=($2-prevVal)           ##Taking difference of 2nd column and prevVal here.
  if(diff>0){ increase++ }    ##If diff is greater than 0 then increase variable with 1
  else      { missing++  }    ##Else increase missing with 1 here.
  print $1": "diff            ##Printing 1st column with diff here.
}
{
  prevVal=$2                  ##Setting prevVal to 2nd column value here.
}
END{                          ##Starting END block of this program from here.
                              ##Printing number of increased or missing/decreased values.
  print "Number increased: "increase+0 ORS "Number missing or equal: " missing+0
}
'  Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```